# Inserting JavaScript files into a markdown-document for documentation purposes

Tags: javascript, markdown

I'am writing a documentation about JavaScript and use markdown as documentation language. I've external JavaScript-files in the same ordner, e.g. `example_0815.js`

I could write in my markdown-document the content of this js-file in backticks, like below:

```
var myData = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three'];

for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
    console.log(myData[i]);
}
```

But I want to link this content to the existing javascript file, so that its content is visible as code in my markdown-document. If I change the content of the javascript-file and open my markdown-document afterwards, I want to see the updated content.

**Why?**

Because, I want to ensure, that every js-file in the documentation is fully tested before and I don't want to update the document, if I change some javascript-files.

Can I do that with markdown? If no, what could I use instead of it?

Comment: Markdown doesn't have a "file import" facility. You would have to use some other system to *generate* the markdown content before viewing.

Comment: ok, thank you, just as I feared :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re on a macOS then [iA Writer](https://ia.net/writer) does that since [version 4](https://ia.net/writer/blog/ia-writer-4/).

[image: Screenshot of the app with the demo of the feature]

They also created [this repo](https://github.com/iainc/Markdown-Content-Blocks) to help others build on that idea.